# ajax autocomplete with typeahead.js not populating

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm attempting to make an auto complete search and it's not working, i'm not sure if it's something with my template of my JSON file is wrong , but i'm getting the dropdown functionality with no results like below:

[image]

### Heading

```
$('#search').typeahead([{                              
        name: 'stooges',
        valueKey: '',
        remote: {
            url: 'application/search/test.json',
            ttl: '0',
            filter: function (parsedResponse) {
                // parsedResponse is the array returned from your backend
                console.log(parsedResponse);

                // do whatever processing you need here
                return parsedResponse;
            }
        },                                             
        template: [                                                                 
            '{{#stooges}}',
    '<b>{{name}}</b>',
    '{{/stooges}}'
        ].join(''),                                                                 
        engine: Hogan // download and include http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/                                                               
    }]);

    });
```

### application/search/test.json

```
{
  "stooges": [
    { "name": "Moe" },
    { "name": "Larry" },
    { "name": "Curly" }
  ]
}
```

### html

```
<input id="search"/>
```

### console output:

[image]

Comment: have u checked the console?

Comment: @sankrish yes, im posting the output above.

Comment: Quick question, are you hosted this application on IIS or IIS express, and whats your console output ??

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani no it's hosted on Nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by remove

```
valueKey: ''
```

Code will be like

```
$('#search').typeahead([{                              
        name: 'stooges',
        remote: {
            url: 'application/search/test.json',
            filter: function (parsedResponse) {
                // parsedResponse is the array returned from your backend
                console.log(parsedResponse);

                // do whatever processing you need here
                return parsedResponse;
            }
        },                                             
        template: [                                                                 
            '{{#stooges}}',
    '<b>{{name}}</b>',
    '{{/stooges}}'
        ].join(''),                                                                 
        engine: Hogan // download and include http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/                                                               
    }]);

    });
```

Please let me know if it going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the filename of the JSON response to match **name** - 'application/search/test.json' -> 'application/search/stooges.json'.